# Resize background color base on child height

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, background-color

Here's my code pen: 
https://codepen.io/sadpandas/pen/KKwgObb

I have a flexbox container and two child divs.
What I am trying to do, is to have a "background color" that matches the height of the textbox, but spans to the sibling div that contains the image.

Without using media queries and upon wrapped, the background color needs to continue to wrap / match the textbox height, but needs to be completely apart from the image.

My current method uses linear-gradient, and a hard coded percentage that approximates how much space I need for the text. I am looking for something more reliable and reusable, as I have several of these sections in my website.

```
.wrapper {
   width: auto;
    max-width: 1686px;
    background:  linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 50%, white 20%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 512px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.right{
  padding-top: 25px;
  flex-basis: 512px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Image of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I am open to using other methods other than linear gradient on the parent to achieve this.
I have doubts that I am using best practices, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

A few more requirements:
- The image on the left cannot be wrapped within the grey background
- The grey background must have the height of the text height, and should resize if the text container increases in height.
- The text cannot poke out of the grey background
- I am refraining from using media-queries due to client requests.
-The image is starting at a slightly lower point than the text on desktop view

Things that I have already tried:
- Using Javascript. Client rejected it as they find it too much of an overkill for getting the height of one container
- Pseudo elements + javascript. Also rejected for similar reasons

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the gray box on the text part only that's where you should put the background property, not on the container that holds both the picture and the text. The other thing is that if you want the gray color to fill the whole hieght of the container you should use `repeating-linear-gradient`rather than `linear-gradient`:

```
.wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 1686px;    
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:  repeating-linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 50%, white 20%);
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 512px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  order: 1;
}

.right{
  padding: 25px;
  flex-basis: 512px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 520px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually need the background to have the height of the textbox, but also to be the "background" of the image.  My image in the original post is showing what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @fishcakesAndCoffee, I have edited the answer to make it look like the image on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use pseudo element on the text container:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 1686px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 512px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.right {
  padding: 25px 0;
  flex-basis: 512px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position:relative;
}
.right:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-100vw;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://www-tc.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/assets/img/fate-of-easter-island/image-01-large.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum., quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum., quis nostrud
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```